# Moving Shipping Estimate Block

Tags: shipping, blocks, design

Right,

Well on the Checkout page, for some reason nearly every FREE/Default theme has placed this in the COL-2 div class underneth the discount code. I can't express how ugly this looks, anyway's what file (phtml / XML) do i need to edit to get it into the COL-1 div..

I've used inspector mode in chrome to copy n paste the code where i want it, to give you guys an idea of what i want to do...

[image]

I want to do the same for the colour options (again its just above the description module and full length of the screen, why colour swatch isnt hardcoded as standard is beyond me).

I want to remove the options div box on that and place it just under the price ... anyways, checkout is more important atm...

Answer (score 2):

Goto **template/checkout/cart.phtml** and move **$this->getChildHtml('shipping')** to another place in the template.